Keep updating text field
I have a springboot 3.3.4 application with Postgresql DB driver version 42.7.4.
I create this entity:
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Acme  {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected UUID id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;


    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    public ArtLuxury() {
        super();
    }

}

In the DB I see correctly a field called description of type TEXT, as well as all the other fields.
In my dev configuration I have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update to update the schema everytime I add some columns.
The problem is that for only fields TEXT, like description in the previous entity example,every time I launch the application hibernate try to alter the column like this,even if it is not necessary:
alter table if exists acme alter column description set data type TEXT


Don't use hibernate to manage your schema.
